# Is There a Term for "Factoring" a Graph by an Equivalence Relation on Nodes?

Tags: graphs, terminology

I have a coding problem I'm running into that feels like it's solved:

Given a (directed) graph, and an equivalence relation on nodes, merge the equivalent nodes in a way that preserves the graph structure to create a "factor" graph, in the sense that every edge connected to one of the equivalent nodes is connected to the new node (in the same orientation, in the directed case).

What, if anything, is this problem called?

I am graph-theory and computer-science illiterate, so excuse me if this is a painfully ubiquitous transformation, but I am having trouble finding anything, likely because I'm stuck thinking about the problem in these mathematical terms.

Comment: You have described the entire construction. What do you mean by "problem"?

Comment: The problem is "construct the best algorithm that performs this operation."
It's a simple enough process that I presume it is named and solved, and its algorithmics are studied.

Comment: You can just go over all the edges in the original graph and add them to the new graph. This runs in linear time.

Comment: One must know at which objects the edges in the original graph are supposed to terminate--the problem is "given a graph and an equivalence relation," so one must do something like constructing a set of representatives of each equivalence class and then testing each of the original edges in relation to the representatives to determine where the original edges ought to terminate in the new graph. It's quite possible that this naïve algorithm isn't optimal, as one may be able to roll the assignment of the new edges into the selection of representatives, as a lot of comparisons are done there.

Comment: I believe my specific problem is solved by implementation detail, as the graph library I'm using implements graphs as a hash-map-of-hash-maps, and setting the hash function of the nodes to be compatible with the equivalence relation means that in adding nodes to the graph I get this behavior for free. I still think the general problem stands, however.

Comment: One professor I had called it "identifying." As in "Identify the equivalent nodes." "A and B are equivalent." "Yes, now identify them please." Whatever you do, don't do that.